# grunt-contrib-cssmin - how to remove comments from minified css

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

Im using cssmin to minify css files.

my config like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('cssmin', {
        site: {
            src: ['.tmp/public/concat/site.css'],
            dest: '.tmp/public/min/site.min.css'
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

But output minified css files has comments.  Is it possible to configure cssmin to remove comment from source css files?

Thank you.

Comment: How I can see, this functionality not provided in cssmin  - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/blob/master/tasks/cssmin.js

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set `keepSpecialComments` to zero, for removing all comments.

```
grunt.config.set('cssmin', {
    options: {
        keepSpecialComments: 0
    },
    site: {
        src: ['.tmp/public/concat/site.css'],
        dest: '.tmp/public/min/site.min.css'
    }
});
```

For future reference: `grunt-contrib-cssmin` uses [`clean-css` options](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically).

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link :)

Comment: According to the site, the option was renamed to "specialComments" in 4.0.0, but neither specialComments:0 nor keepSpecialComments:0 seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question but now you can use it like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.set('cssmin', {
    options: {
      level: {
        1: {
          specialComments: 0
        }
      }
    },
    site: {
      src: ['.tmp/public/concat/site.css'],
      dest: '.tmp/public/min/site.min.css'
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
};
```

[clean-css #How to apply level 1 & 2 optimizations at the same time?](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-apply-level-1--2-optimizations-at-the-same-time)