# Is there a way to remove important comments?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, minify, build-system

I minified my css file, but it did not get rid of 
`/*! important comments */`.

**is there a way to get rid of important comments?**

I found this - 
[grunt-contrib-cssmin - how to remove comments from minified css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825744/grunt-contrib-cssmin-how-to-remove-comments-from-minified-css?answertab=votes#answer-27826096)
but @Rigotti answer does not work for important comments.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many grunt plugins will not remove the important comments as the notation `/*! */` is typically used to prevent removal. However, [grunt-strip-css-comment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-strip-css-comments), provides the option to remove them.

You could apply the following `stripCssComments` Task to your minified `.css` file.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      // ...
    },
    stripCssComments: {
        options: {
          preserve: false // <-- Option removes important comments.
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                // Redefine paths as necessary.
                // These should probably both be the same given your scenario.
                'path/to/dest/file.min.css': 'path/to/src/file.min.css'
            }
        }
    }
  });

  // Define the alias to the `stripCssComments` Task after your `cssmin` Task. 
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin', 'stripCssComments']);
};
```

**Install:**

`cd` to your project directory and run:

```
npm i -D grunt-strip-css-comments load-grunt-tasks
```

Note: `grunt-strip-css-comments` is loaded using the plugin [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) instead of the typical `grunt.loadNpmTasks(...)` notation, so you'll need to install that too.